# How to set session.cookie value httponly in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am using Codeigniter framework for the development and I have to apply some security on my application. I want my cookies to have httponly attribute to be applied throughout the application via some config changes. I have done following changes in my application/config file

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;
```

I have set changes for my php.ini file

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
```

After above said changes I am able to see cookie attributes are changed to httponly on my local server but when I deployed the application on live server, it doesn't worked. I am unable to understand what additional changes I need to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

httpponly cookies are supported by https enabled sites like https://www.samplewebsite.com and you don't need to set it manually. Just ask your service provider to change the "cookie_httponly" value to be true or if you have server access, set it yourself. You can also apply below code to your .htaccess file.

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;HttpOnly
Header set Set-Cookie "%{http_cookie}e; HTTPOnly" env=http_cookie
```

Comment: The two lines in this answer did not work for me, but the first line on its own did.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here and the answer is fairly straight forward.  You need to modify one function in one of the CodeIgniter system libraries, system/libraries/Session.php, as follows:

```
/**
* Write the session cookie
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  void
 */
function _set_cookie($cookie_data = NULL)
{
    if (is_null($cookie_data))
    {
        $cookie_data = $this->userdata;
    }

    // Serialize the userdata for the cookie
    $cookie_data = $this->_serialize($cookie_data);

    if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
    {
        $cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
    }
    else
    {
        // if encryption is not used, we provide an md5 hash to prevent userside tampering
        $cookie_data = $cookie_data.md5($cookie_data.$this->encryption_key);
    }

    $expire = ($this->sess_expire_on_close === TRUE) ? 0 : $this->sess_expiration + time();

    // Set the cookie
    setcookie(
                $this->sess_cookie_name,
                $cookie_data,
                $expire,
                $this->cookie_path,
                $this->cookie_domain,
                $this->cookie_secure,
                true// <-- SYSTEM LIBRARY MODIFICATION TO SET httpOnly to true!!
            );
}
```

The above function called _set_cookie() needs one additional parameter which will force the all cookies to be HTTP Only.
You could probably extend this library and add the new version of the function (recommended) but I have just hard-coded it here for simplicity.

Comment: I have done the changes and it shows httponly cookies as earlier in my local development environment but no luck with production environment. Also I am wondering if somewhere it is dependent on site type i.e. whether http or https and might would work with https?

Comment: I have just figured out and come to know that the above settings will work only if your application is on ssl deployment i.e. https

Comment: What version of CI was this for? Doesn't seem up to date for CI 3